# How can I access Box Drive offline folders when the Box Drive app is not running?

Tags: windows, box.com

The Box Drive app for Windows (ver 2.0 and above) allows you to mark a folder as offline. Any file stored in an offline folder can be accessed without an Internet connection.

I would like to access my Box offline files **even when the Box Drive app is not running.** But I can't find any way to do this.

When Box Drive is running, the following folder shows up in my user directory, containing all my Box content:

```
06/01/2023  10:45 AM    <JUNCTION>     Box [\??\Volume{6b37c027-ea95-11ed-b537-63fa9b9f2fa8}\]
```

I can `cd` into this directory and access offline folders and their contents without a problem.

But when the Box Drive app is not running, this Box folder disappears from my user directory. Obviously, the files in the offline folders are stored *somewhere* on my hard drive, but where?

I searched for the directory listed in the junction but didn't find it:

```
C:\>dir /s Volume{6b37c027-ea95-11ed-b537-63fa9b9f2f}
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is EE34-8955
File Not Found
```

Googling about access to Box Drive offline folders didn't turn anything up, either.

Comment: Check the Box Cache folder at `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Box\Box\cache` ([link](https://support.box.com/hc/en-us/articles/360043695894-Technical-Information-for-Box-Drive-Administrators)).

Answer (score 0):

Since the location might vary, you could run a file system monitoring tool such as Nirsoft's free [FolderChangesView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/folder_changes_view.html), and see where new offline files go *on your PC*.

- Start the monitoring tool.
- Add or remove some offline folders.
- Review the changes shown in that tool.